# how to let my form stop taking empty values in the database?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, validation

I am working on a library management project using html5,php and sql.Currently I am working on form validation using php.Validation are applied on email,password,name,surname,phone number .The validation works(atleast visually) but it takes empty entries in the database.So how to solve this problem?

## **Html code**

```
<?php
 require '..\\model\signup.php';
 require '..\\model\adu.php';
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <style media="screen">
    
    main{
      margin-left:300px;
      margin-top:70px;
    }
    </style>

    <title>Create Librarian</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php include '..\\templates\dashboard.php'; ?>
  <main>
    <h3 class="my-4">Create new librarian</h3>
    <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
    <form  action="createlibrarian.php" method="post" name="">
      <div class="form-group" >

       
       <label class="mt-2" for="name">Name</label>
       <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $fname;?>">
       <span class="error" style="color:red">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
      
      
       <label class="mt-2" for="surname">Surname</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>">
       <span class="error" style="color:red">* <?php echo $lnameErr;?></span>
       <br><br> 

       <label class="mt-2" for="email">Email</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
       <span class="error" style="color:red">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
       <br><br>

       
       <label class="mt-2" for="password">Password</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $pass;?>">
       <span class="error" style="color:red">* <?php echo $passErr;?></span>
       <br><br>      

   
       <label class="mt-2" for="phone">Phone</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">
       <span class="error" style="color:red">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
       <br><br>   




       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create" class="mt-2 btn btn-primary">
       
      </div>


    </form>

   </main>


  </body>
</html>
```

## **php code**

```
<?php

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
// define variables and set to empty values
$fnameErr = $lnameErr= $emailErr = $passErr = $phoneErr = "";
$fname = $email = $lname = $pass = $phone = "";

$flag;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
    $flag=false;
  } else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    $flag= false;
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      return false;
    }
  }
    
  if (empty($_POST["surname"])) {
    $lnameErr = "Surname is required";
    $flag= false;
  } else {
    $lname = test_input($_POST["surname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
      $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      return false;
    }
  }

   if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passErr = "Password is required";
    $flag= false;
  } else {
    $pass = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    $uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password);
  $lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $password);
 $number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $password);
 $specialChars = preg_match('@[^\w]@', $password);
    if(!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || !$specialChars || strlen($password) < 8) {
    echo 'Password should be at least 8 characters in length and should include at least one upper case letter, one number, and one special character.';
      return false;
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phoneErr = "phone number is required";
  $flag= false;
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{5}$/",$phone)) {
      $phoneErr = "phone number should be numeric ";
      return false;
    }
  }
return $flag;

echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $fname;
echo "<br>";
echo $lname;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $pass;
echo "<br>";
echo $phone;
echo "<br>";




}
?>
```

how to solve this issue?

Comment: I hope you're not planning on using this code in  a live environment.

Comment: What do you want to do if an empty value is detected?

Comment: Where does the data get written to the database?

Comment: Where's the code used to insert data into the database? you need to check for empty values before that moment

Comment: [Don't run inputs through htmlspecialchars](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/). That makes no sense. You're not going to use them in HTML (at this point), you're using it in an SQL query. So you have to deal with SQL, not HTML. Use htmlspecialchars if and when you're *outputting* HTML, not before. Also, it completely breaks the validation you're trying to do. You don't end up with "Only letters and white space", for instance. You are *actively changing users' passwords*. This is precisely the problem with escaping in the wrong place.

Comment: @Peter     ``` (this is my sql query code) <?php
 require '..\\model\connect.php';
 if($_POST){
   $con = Opencon();
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $surname = $_POST['surname'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $sql = "insert into adduser (name,surname,email,password,phone) values ('$name','$surname','$email','$password','$phone')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }


?>```

Comment: guys please help me with this plz beacause I have project report submission on 25th april

Answer (score 0):

Your validation looks correct. I would add a "required" attribute in yout  tags:

`<input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" required>`

And also make sure you have a NOT NULL constraint in you SQL columns. You can modify existing columns this way:

`ALTER TABLE Person MODIFY name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;`

Comment: This isn't the answer. `required` attribute specifies that an input field must be filled.

Comment: the fields are already set to not null as while creating the tables in xamp phpmyadmin,the null check box was unchecked so evyer table is not null so what's the problem